# Lucene query from Hadoop PIG jobs

Tags: hadoop, lucene, apache-pig

I have couple of thousands of customer names, alternative names, business names etc details indexed in Lucene indexes (indexes are not stored in HDFS).

I have massive amount (>100M) of person data in HDFS and I want to scan person data with Lucene indexes, I am currently using PIG for data processing from HDFS.

I am trying to find if it is possible to run PIG job which extracts data and in-parallel perform queries to Lucene indexes (may be by using custom written UDF), I am not able to think how Lucene local indexes are loaded and shared within PIG jobs (after Lucene query I need matched document IDs if match is found).

Is it possible using PIG ? or I need to write custom map-reduce jobs for this ? Or any other suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need UDFs for that - elephant-bird's lucene loader is a good starting point.
Check it out at https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/tree/master/pig

Comment: Thanks SNeumann, looks like this will help, I am not clear on how I can retrieve query results from PIG jobs, I think I need to read more.